# setState at MouseWheel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousewheel

Собственно запускаю setState при прокрутки мышью, начинает все тормозить, может даже "зависнуть" хром

```
_handleScroll (el, event) {
    var delta = event.deltaY || event.detail || event.wheelDelta;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    delta,
                };
            }, () => {
                console.log('end')
                console.log(this.state.delta);
            }
        );
}
receive(el) {
    el.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
        this._handleScroll(el, event)
    }, false);
}
```

В чем проблема? обрабатывать setState асинхронно?

Comment: Во-первых, Вы используете внутри реактовских компонентов родные браузерные события вместо синтетических реактовских. Вы уверены в том что делаете?  Во вторых Вы вешаете обработчик каждый раз заново, а старый не удаляете, по крайней мере в этом коде. Если у вас recieve выполняется много раз, то у вас в определенный момент копится вагон этих обработчиков. В-третьих это дело очевидно надо дебаунсить, если нормально крутануть колесико эвент зажжется много раз.

Comment: Используются рефералы
<div className="inner"  ref={(el) => {
        el ? this.receive(el) : null
       }}>    
Заново, новый обработчик через него не вешается

Comment: Это чертовски мутная конструкция и я признаться с ходу не могу понять ее смысл. Не могли бы Вы пояснить ее?